# PHPMailer .xlsx attachment either doesn't send or is corrupted on arrival

Tags: php, excel, phpmailer, email-attachments

So I've spent the last 3 days trying to figure out why the email I'm trying to send from PHP won't attach my excel file. It's a file that is generated on the server and I've verified that the .xlsx file is being created without error, but when I receive the email that it should be attached to, there is nothing there.

I found an answer here on SO that suggested trying to attach it as a string instead. This made it so I was able to see the attachment when I opened the email, but the file was corrupted and could not be opened in excel.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From = 'my@email.address';
$email->addReplyTo('my@email.address');
$email->FromName = 'My Name';
$email->Subject = $reportName;
$email->Body = 'Here is your report good sir.';
$email->AddAddress('myother@test.email');

$fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $reportName;
$email->addAttachment($fullPath, 'Session_Report.xlsx', 'base64',
       'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
$email->Send();
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: This code looks ok, though you don't need to set the name, encoding or type as that will be done automatically. Adding it as a string shouldn't make any difference - that only changes where the data comes from, not how the attachment is created. You need to show exactly *how* it is corrupted.

Comment: For anyone wondering, it turned out that this code was perfectly fine. The problem was that I was returning a filepath through shell_exec() that was generated with a python script. For some reason there was an extra space at the end of the filepath upon return and this caused problems when trying to attach the document to the email.